# How to maintain different version of reports/documents?

Tags: java, web-applications

What is the best and most flexible way of maintaining different version of documents for a web application?

Let's say you have a Pet store web application.You need to make changes to a printable document with info of your Pet, but these changes are only effective for every Pet object created from a x date , but for Pets created before x date then use the previous version of the report. Somehow keeping multiple versions of the files and choosing them with hardcoded rules seems messy, is there any other way?

Comment: are you using Microsoft's SQLServer Reporting Services, or did you include the reporting-services tag to indicate a reporting requirement?

Comment: I am not using any reporting engine, It's a reporting requirement but I guess the tag is not warranted in this case. I Have removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you simply need to bind your `Pet` objects to `DocumentTemplate` objects. You could just add a field to the `Pet` object:

```
public class Pet {

    private final String name;
    private final Template template;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

This way you would not need to make checks like:

```
if (pet.getCreationDate().after(date)) {
    print(template1);
}
else {
    print(template2);
}
```

but you can simply do:

```
print(pet.getTemplate());
```

This would be the standard way to do it if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Correct. But do you mean the template should be stored in the db?

Comment: What if this is not an option? say the document/report was created after the entities were stored in the db.

Comment: Yes you should somehow bind them continuously. I mean for every new `Pet` you should also bind a template, also you need to bind your current pets to templates. If they are already in the DB you can make a Templates table containing foreign keys to the Pets table or something similar depending on what you need. With my answer I generally mean: If you don't want to check every time - you should bind Pets to Templates in some way. If you need a more specific answer give me more info :)

Comment: Thanks, that makes it pretty clear. One last question... would it be a good idea to store the actual template in a database or would a link to a file inside the project be best? thanks.

Comment: Depends on what you need I'd say. If you need to change the templates at runtime the database would probably be better. Files in the project while (probably) easier to change would probably be harder to change dynamically. Although of it was me I would most likely keep them in the project for readability/maintainability reasons.